# How to redirect output from schtasks taskeng.exe

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hudson

We're running Sikuli app from a CI tool Hudson.
A scheduled task is configured on our windows server 2008, named test
When Hudson job kicks off, it triggered the command schtasks /run /tn test.
A windows shell pops up by taskeng.exe and as Sikuli app executes, the output is shown on the windows shell.

How do we direct it to a file since we like to use it to troubleshoot.
Right now when it fails, the shell disappears.

Advance thanks

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to [configure logging for Sikuli](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/165999), rather than simply redirecting the output.